# PullCommand throws 'Nothing to fetch' exception in JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am using JGit library in my project.
Here is my JGit util class:

```
public class GitUtil {

    private static final RefSpec REF_SPEC = new RefSpec(Constants.GIT_REF_SPEC);
    private static final RefSpec REMOTE_REF_SPEC = new RefSpec(Constants.GIT_REMOTE_REF_SPEC);
    private static final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(Constants.GIT_REMOTE_USER_NAME, Constants.GIT_REMOTE_PASSWORD);
    private static Git git;
    @Autowired
    private HibernateUtilServiceImpl hibernateUtilServiceImpl;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initGitRepository() throws Exception {
        File file = new File(Constants.GIT_REPOSITORY_MAIN_FILE_PATH);
        FileRepositoryBuilder repositoryBuilder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
        repositoryBuilder.addCeilingDirectory(file);
        repositoryBuilder.findGitDir(file);
        if (repositoryBuilder.getGitDir() == null) {
            git = Git.init().setDirectory(file.getParentFile()).call();
            StoredConfig config = git.getRepository().getConfig();
            config.setString("remote", "origin", "url", Constants.GIT_HSQLDB_REMOTE_REPOSTITORY_URL);
            RemoteConfig remoteConfig = new RemoteConfig(config, "remote");
            remoteConfig.addURI(new URIish(git.getRepository().getDirectory().toURI().toURL()));
            remoteConfig.update(config);
            config.save();
        } else {
            git = new Git(repositoryBuilder.build());
        }
        addUntrackedFiles(git.status().call().getUntracked(), git.getRepository());
    }

    public void commitAndPush() throws Exception {
        hibernateUtilServiceImpl.dumpDataBase();
        addUntrackedFiles(git.status().call().getUntracked(), git.getRepository());
        addChangedFiles(git.status().call().getModified(), git.getRepository());
        git.commit().setMessage("Update").call();
        git.push().setRemote("origin")
                .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .setRefSpecs(REF_SPEC)
                .call();
    }

    public void pullAndMerge() throws GitAPIException, IOException {
        git.pull().call();
        hibernateUtilServiceImpl.backupDataBaseFromServer();
    }

    private void addUntrackedFiles(Collection<String> notTracked, Repository repository) throws Exception {
        if (notTracked == null || notTracked.size() == 0)
            return;
        AddCommand addCommand = git.add();
        for (String path : notTracked) {
            addCommand.addFilepattern(path);
        }
        addCommand.call();
    }

    private void addChangedFiles(Collection<String> changed, Repository repository) throws GitAPIException {
        if (changed == null || changed.size() == 0)
            return;
        AddCommand addCommand = git.add();
        for (String path : changed) {
            addCommand.addFilepattern(path);
        }
        addCommand.call();
    }
}
```

My config git config file in the .git folder:

```
[core]
    symlinks = false
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://bitbucket.com/<my-profile>/<my-repository>.git
[remote "remote"]
    url = file:///D:/database/.git/
[gui]
    wmstate = zoomed
    geometry = 443x321+75+75 171 192
```

Almost all methods work except pullAndMerge method.
I am gettin this exception:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: Nothing to fetch.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullCommand.call(PullCommand.java:267)
    at com.uz.laboratory.statistical.util.GitUtil.pullAndMerge(GitUtil.java:61)
    at com.uz.laboratory.statistical.controller.settings.SettingsController.updateCurrentDatabaseButtonListener(SettingsController.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: Nothing to fetch.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:128)
    ... 65 more
```

I can't figure out how to fix it.
Can you please give some advice and some code example to fix this issue?
And maybe example code of correct pull by jgit.
Thanks.

**Update:**

Thank you for your answers Stanislav and Rudiger Herrmann... But when I added this lines:

```
public static final String GIT_REMOTE_REF_SPEC = "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*";
        ...
private static final RefSpec REMOTE_REF_SPEC = new RefSpec(Constants.GIT_REMOTE_REF_SPEC);
    ...
//a have added this to my initGitRepository() method.
    RemoteConfig originConfig = new RemoteConfig(config, "origin");
                        originConfig.addFetchRefSpec(REMOTE_REF_SPEC);
                        originConfig.update(config);
                        config.save();
```

My past issue now is fixed, but I have a new problem, after this changes:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotAdvertisedException: Remote origin did not advertise Ref for branch master. This Ref may not exist in the remote or may be hidden by permission settings.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullCommand.call(PullCommand.java:294)
    at com.uz.laboratory.statistical.util.GitUtil.pullAndMerge(GitUtil.java:64)
    at com.uz.laboratory.statistical.controller.settings.SettingsController.updateCurrentDatabaseButtonListener(SettingsController.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems, you have not properly configured `[remote "remote"]` section. You have to add there this property

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

It makes Git fetching all the `refs/heads/` and storing them locally as `refs/remotes/origin/`. [Here](https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) is some more information to read about.

Comment: Thanks Stanislav, it helped :) 
But now I have a new problem with new exception. I will create a new question for a few minutes, maybe you can look out.

Comment: @AlexeyShabramov glad to help you) If this solved the problem you can accept the answer to make it easier to someone else with the same problem to find an answer

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurs if you try to fetch a ref that does not exist on the remote end.

For example, given a refspec like `refs/heads/foo:refs/remotes/origin/foo`, and there is no `foo` branch on the remote end, this exception arises.

I think asking for a non-existing ref isn't an error and JGit shouldn't raise an exception in this case. Rather an appropriate `FetchResult` should be returned so that application code can detect this situation and act accordingly.

However, with the current state, you could work around the issue in that you catch the exception and try to figure this case from the exception message.

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for your answer. Can you please check my updates in the question, maybe you can give some advice. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a different question altogether and should be posted separately.